# Google Calendar API v3 cant add event php

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

hey cant seem to create an event with this code,

```
  <?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/apiClient.php'
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/apiCalendarService.php';
session_start();
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("Cal");
$client->setClientId('');
$client->setClientSecret('');
//$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost:8080/createEvent.php');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost:8080/eventNew.php');
//http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback');
$client->setDeveloperKey('');
$cal = new apiCalendarService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {

$event = new Event();
$event->setSummary("test title");
$event->setLocation("test location");
$start = new EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('04-03-2012 09:25:00:000 -05:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('04-03-2012 10:25:00:000 -05:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
//$attendee1 = new EventAttendee();
//$attendee1->setEmail('email@email.com');
//$attendees = array($attendee1);
//$event->attendees = $attendees;
$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('primary', $event);

echo $createdEvent->getId();

$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
?>
```

Keep getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'apiIOException' with message 'HTTP Error: (0) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed' in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\google-api-php-client\src\io\apiCurlIO.php:119 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\google-api-php-client\src\io\apiCurlIO.php(56): apiCurlIO->makeRequest(Object(apiHttpRequest)) #1 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\google-api-php-client\src\io\apiREST.php(55): apiCurlIO->authenticatedRequest(Object(apiHttpRequest)) #2 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\google-api-php-client\src\service\apiServiceResource.php(186): apiREST::execute(Object(apiServiceRequest)) #3 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\google-api-php-client\src\contrib\apiCalendarService.php(493): apiServiceResource->__call('insert', Array) #4 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\eventNew.php(47): EventsServiceResource->insert('primary', Object(Event)) #5 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\google-api-php-client\src\io\apiCurlIO.php on line 119

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your version of PHP on Windows is not set up to verify peer SSL certificates.

There is some information at [this link](http://richardwarrender.com/2007/05/the-secret-to-curl-in-php-on-windows/) which describes how to fix the problem.

Basically, you need to install the CA bundle on the Windows machine and then add one line to your code, telling it where to look for the CA bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Some programs already have CA bundles with them.

I've used the GIT certificate bundle before when I was having this problem.